# Binding gridview with xml file at client side

Tags: asp.net, gridview

hi i have two xml file and i want to bind grid view eith this xml file on client side. i try to describe the complete senerio. in my .aspx page i have a drop down list which has number of department. when the user select the department the data i want the data according to department comes on the grid view from first xml file, in this gridview the rows are field with various tests and the row also have a checkboxes ,when user click on that checkbox the datafrom yhe second xml file will come and the second grid view is bind with that data. i want all that on client side. how is that possible, please help me and thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to either use jqgrid/html table and use [this](http://dotnetacademy.blogspot.com/2010/09/load-xml-using-javascript-works-with.html) article to read xml using javascript or if you wants to use gridview only and don't wants to show post back to the user then use updatepannel with gridview will help you out.

Comment: i my page lots of time request is going to server, update panel is also not a solution for this .I want to do complete work at client Side

Comment: @user1023160: then i think you will have to leave gridview, because its a server side control.. you can do manipulation in it using javascript but even though its not suitable for situation where you wants complete client side operations.

Comment: so what i choose,if i leave the grid view, which can handle all these tasks